# KL divergence between Bernoulli Distribution with parameter $p$ and Gaussian Distribution

Tags: real-analysis, statistics

I am trying to find the [Kullback–Leibler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#KL_divergence_for_Normal_Distributions) divergence between [Bernoulli Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) on two points $T, -T$ with parameter $p$ and [Gaussian Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. My attempt is as follows:

Let
$$
b(x) = q\delta(x-T)+p\delta(x+T) \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p) \\ g(x) \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2).
$$

$$
\begin{align}
D(b||g) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}b(x)\log \left( \frac{b(x)}{g(x)}\right) dx \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}b(x)\log \left( b(x) \right) dx - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}b(x)\log \left( g(x) \right) dx \\ 
&=A-B
\end{align}
$$

My questions are as follows:

1. Can I use the continuous representation of Bernoulli RV with the help of $\delta(.)$ functions where $\delta(.)$ is [Dirac Delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) function?
2. Does $A$ exist? Because, on the set $\mathbb{R}-\{\pm T\}$, $\log(\delta(x \mp T))$ is $-\infty$.
3. If we cannot calculate the KLD between a continuous and a discrete random variable, what is the KLD analogue for this case? My thought was that $B$ alone can serve as a distance. For example, if we want to measure the distance of $b(x)$ from two different Gaussian distributions $g_1(x), g_2(x)$, only $B$ depends on $g_1(x)$ or $g_2(x)$, and thus can contribute to KLD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, you cannot do this. The Kullback-Leibler divergence $D_{KL}(P\|Q)$ is defined only if $P\ll Q$.  This means that no set of positive $P$-measure can have zero $Q$-measure.  In your case it will not work because the point masses of the Bernoulli distribution have zero measure under the Gaussian distribution.
2. The integral A blows up.  For a continuous distribution this would the negative of the continuous version of the Shannon entropy.
3. I suspect that you might be looking for the **[mutual information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information)** between parameter space and observation space.  It is a common technique to try to maximize the mutual information in such settings.  The mutual information is then equal to the *expected* Kullback-Leibler divergence of the posterior distribution on a parameter space (given the observations) from the prior distribution.  Here, the requirement that $P\ll Q$ simply means that one is not allowed to make any conclusions that are *a priori* impossible!