# clarification about the kl divergence between a continuous and a discrete distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, machine-learning, information-theory

I was reading this [blog post](https://www.uv.es/gonmagar/blog/2018/03/15/BayesianNeuralNetworks#map-variational-inference-relation) on bayesian neural networks, where the author shows that if we use as a variational distribution a product of delta function, then minimizing the loss function of a BNN is equivalent to minimize  the loss function of a standard neural network with a l2 regularization mechanism.
However, I have read here on [mathematics.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164744/kl-divergence-between-bernoulli-distribution-with-parameter-p-and-gaussian-dis) that the Kl divergence is only defined between continuous distribution and not between discrete and continuous distribution, so I was wondering if the demonstration is still approximatively right or not and if not, what changes should be made. thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, so, the maths of this is *very* sloppy, but this is common with such exposition in applied contexts. Here I believe the argument the author wants to make is that if the posterior were to be a point, then the ELBO objective would reduce to a standard one. This basic point I think is quite true.

---

To get at this somewhat sensibly, take $q_{\theta, \varepsilon}$ to be normal around $\theta$ with a variance $\varepsilon I$. Think of this $\varepsilon$ as something small that is introduced for convenience, but that we're not optimising over (and will eventually send to $0$).  Then the first term becomes $$ \int \frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi \varepsilon})^K} e^{-\|\omega - \theta \|^2/2\varepsilon} \log p(y_i|f^\omega(x_i) ) \mathrm{d}\omega,$$ and the second becomes (this comes from the KL between multivariate Gaussians) $$ \frac{K}{2} \log \frac{1}{\lambda\varepsilon} - \frac K2 + K \lambda \varepsilon +  \frac{\lambda}{2} \|\theta\|^2 = g(\varepsilon) + - \frac{K}{2} \log \lambda + \frac{\lambda}{2} \|\theta\|^2 + K \lambda\varepsilon. $$

Now, here notice that $g(\varepsilon)$ is uninteresing from the point of view of a loss, since it doesn't interact with $\theta$ - the only thing we're optimising over. In optimisation terms this is like adding a constant to the objective function - this doesn't change anything about the solution of the optimisation problem. So from the perspective of deriving a loss on $\theta$, it is perfectly fine to drop this term. The same is actually true for the $K \lambda \varepsilon$ and other terms (but maybe they're also optimising over $\lambda,$ I don't know).

Note by the way that $g(\varepsilon)$ explodes as $\varepsilon \to 0$. This is related to the fact that the KL divergence between a discrete and continuous distribution is $\infty$.

In any case, accounting for all the $\theta$ and $\lambda$ dependent terms, the loss we end up with takes the form $$ \mathcal{L}_\varepsilon(\theta) :=  \sum_i \int \frac{1}{(\sqrt{2\pi \varepsilon})^K} e^{-\|\omega - \theta \|^2/2\varepsilon} \log p(y_i|f^\omega(x_i) ) \mathrm{d}\omega -\frac{K}{2} \log \lambda + \frac{\lambda}{2} \|\theta\|^2 + K \lambda \varepsilon. $$

Now, as $\varepsilon \to 0$, observe that $q_{\theta, \varepsilon}$ converges to $q_\theta$ (in some sense, but that's not too important), the integral converes to $\log p(y_i|f^\theta(x_i))$ (under some smoothness assumptions), and the final term goes to $0$. This gives the form of the loss they're motivating, the important terms of which are $$ \sum_i \log p(y_i|f^\theta(x_i)) + \lambda \|\theta\|^2/2 - K/2 \log \lambda.$$

---

Again, this is quite sloppy, but it does give something meaningful. In part the issue is that they're making the framework do something that it shouldn't - ultimately a Bayesian estimate would never be a point, but would be a distribution. So if you force it to be a point, then some weird things are going to happen. Ideally the author would have been explicit about considerations such as the above rather than hiding them away (and dropped other irrelevant terms like the  $K/2$ term), but maybe this distracts from the context of the writeup a bit too much.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i am a bit confused on 2 things: is there a log missing in the first term or am i wrong? 2) $f(\epsilon)$ is different from $f(x)^{\omega}, right? the latter should be the function approximated  by the neural network, right?

Comment: You're right on both counts, I've edited appropriately. Thanks.

Comment: hi, sorry to bother you once again, i was trying to derive the kl term by comparing the result with what is reported here https://leenashekhar.github.io/2019-01-30-KL-Divergence/ and i am having some trouble with the result.  in bayesian neural networks the priors are fixed so $\lambda$ it's fixed (it's your epsilon i think) but in the formula there are both

Comment: Apply [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60680/kl-divergence-between-two-multivariate-gaussians) with $\mu_1 = \theta, \Sigma_1 = \varepsilon I, \mu_2 = 0, \Sigma_2 = \lambda^{-1} I$ (and of course $d = K$).

Comment: Hi, i know a lot of time passed, but today i was reading again this answer you gave me and i wondered what did you mean with "(in some sense, but that's not too important)" when talking about the convergence. During this time i have learned that when computers sample from a gaussian distribution with a variance close to the machine precision (10^{-33}) there is a high probability that the realization is rounded to the mean. Maybe this is the reason why the posterior can be reduced to a point estimate.